# Is there any .NET binding for Neo4J?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

Is there a .NET version/binding for Neo4j?

It looks like exactly what I want, but I'm working in C# on .NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you best bet at the moment is to use the [REST server](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started_REST). There's a blog post with a proof of concept .NET client: [Neo4j .NET Client over HTTP using REST and json](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/04/16/neo4j-net-client-over-http-using-rest-and-json/).

**Update:** Now there's actually two different .Net Neo4j REST clients:

- [Neo4RestNet](http://bitbucket.org/2hdddg/neo4restnet/)
- [Neo4jRestSharp](http://neo4jrestsharp.codeplex.com/)

Comment: oh, I was hoping for something with a C# client library/bindings.  I don't suppose you know of something similar to Neo4j in the C# world?

Comment: not sure about similarity to Neo4j, but have a look over here for a list of graph databases: http://graph-database.org/

Comment: Here's a getting started: http://blog.noop.se/archive/2010/04/16/neo4j-net-client-over-http-using-rest-and-json.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Just updating this question with a more current option - the Neo4jClient available on NuGet. The package and links to the project site are at http://nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient

Comment: Neo4JClient is very up to date to the latest versions and supports most of the REST API.